# Is it possible to create a filter for a range generated from UNIQUE?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have two tables, one containing the sales history by each person and another one a summary of the sales history.

By using `UNIQUE`, I can get a unique list of people from the sales history. I would like to also be able to create a filter and sort the summary table by person or by total items sold. However, with using `UNIQUE`, creating a filter would not work.

Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple query formula.

```
=QUERY(U2:V10,"select U, sum(V) group by U label sum(V) 'Total Items sold' ")
```

*(You can adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Please read more about [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)